# ASP.NET Core not accepting custom header variable from Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have an Angular based frontend and ASP.NET Core 3 based APIs.

I want to send custom variable in each of API request and read it in API but I'm getting this error:

**Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error : HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse**

On ASP.NET side, I added this setting:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(corsOrigin)
                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .WithExposedHeaders("clinicalsiteid");
                    });
            });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.AddScoped<IPatientRepository, PatientRepository>();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Connexus", Version = "v1" });
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

        ....
    }
```

Here is how I'm reading header variable:

```
    public static int? GetClinicalSiteIDFromHeader(HttpRequest request, bool raiseExceptionIfNotFound)
    {
        StringValues sids;
        string sid = null;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValue("clinicalsiteid", out sids))
            sid = sids.FirstOrDefault();

        if (raiseExceptionIfNotFound && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sid))
        {
            throw new SecurityException("No clinical site id provided in headers");
        }

        try
        {
            return int.Parse(sid);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I want to read **clinicalsiteid** from request headers.
Here is the Angular code:

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
 constructor() { }
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 let newHeaders = req.headers;

 let currentSite = localStorage.getItem('currentSite');

 const siteJSON =  JSON.parse(currentSite);
 newHeaders = newHeaders.append("x-clinicalsiteid", String(siteJSON.clinicalSiteID));

 // Finally we have to clone our request with our new headers
 // This is required because HttpRequests are immutable
 const authReq = req.clone({headers: newHeaders});
 return next.handle(authReq)
  .pipe(
    map(resp => {
      if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {
        ...
      }
    })
  );
}
}
```

Is it possible to read customer header variables? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you calling app.UseCors() in the Configure method?

Comment: Do I need to since I'm using AddDefaultPolicy()? I tried app.UseCors() but same error